# Reading CSV File but showing old data

Tags: c#, csv

I am reading a small csv file on 2 pages using the same code. On localhost using a local csv file everything works! On the server, however it works on Page1 but Page2 appears to be showing old data.

I call getDataCSV() from each page and return a string

```
 string getDataCSV()
    {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        string filePath = utility.GetAbsPathFile(orgWebSite, "files", "UDAP_Donors.csv");

        IEnumerable<string[]> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Select(a => a.Split(','));
        //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
        s.Append("<div class='donor_level'>Level 1</div>|");
        s.Append(getData2(lines,"C"));
        s.Append("<div class='donor_level'>Level 2</div>|");
        s.Append(getData2(lines, "R"));
        ....
        return s.ToString();
    }
    string getData2(IEnumerable<string[]> lines, string x)
    {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        var corp = from line in lines where line[1].Equals(x) orderby line[0] select line;
        foreach (var c in corp)
        {
            s.Append(getString(c[0].ToString()));
        }
        return s.ToString();
    }
    string getString(string c)
    {
        return string.Format(@"<div class='donor'><div class='donor_name'>{0}</div></div> |", c.Replace("'", "\'"));
    }
```

On Page 1 I am taking this string and adding it into a js scroller - works fine.

On Page 2 I am just putting the string into a literal control. The data shown here, tho, is from the 1st csv file I uploaded, I have since overwritten (or deleted and reuoloaded) several times.

I have added some dummy characters to the return strings and these characters show on both pages so I know the code is being called.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

this is the code for page 2

```
 public string GetDonations2(string yr)
    {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.AppendFormat(@"<div class='donor_thanks'>Thank You to the Sponsors</div><div class='donor'><br /></div>");
        s.Append(getDataCSV());
        return s.ToString();
    }
```

this then gets assigned to a literal

the string going to page 1 gets wrapped in some js ... but that works... the only reference to the file is the string filePath way above

Comment: the only difference in the string sent back is the "|" character.  I used this as a delimiter for the scroller , I remove it from the string on page 2

Comment: This sounds more like an asp.net issue, I suspect caching. Can you post the relevant part of your code-behnd/controller which uses the  result of `getDataCSV()`?

Comment: @Rhumborl - code added above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved ... page 2 was not getting the value for orgWebSite and by accident was reading an old file that had been uploaded to that same location - aargh